# Fourth moment of a random-variable with block-tridiagonal structure

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, graph-theory, st.statistics

Let x be a random variable in $\mathbb{R}^d$, $J$ a block tridiagonal $d\times d$ matrix, and probability of $x$ is defined as follows

$$p(x)\propto \exp(-x'Jx)$$

For a fixed $d\times d$ matrix $v$ compute $u$

$$u_{ij}=\sum_{kl}E[x_i x_j x_k x_l] v_{kl}$$

How can this be done efficiently and what is the algorithm to compute this?

It feels like Isserlis theorem should make this computation much faster than $O(d^4)$, but I'm having trouble finding a source that worked through the details.

Comment: Is $\exp$ missing in the definition of $p$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using e.g. the Gauss elimination, we can diagonalize the matrix $(v_{kl})$, that is, write
$$v_{kl}=\sum_{r=1}^d a_r s_{rk}t_{rl}$$
for some real $a_r,s_{rk},t_{rl}$ and all $k,l$; the computational complexity (CC) of this diagonalization is $O(d^3)$; cf. e.g. [this source](https://nholmber.github.io/2018/05/mpi-diagonalization/).

Now we can write
$$u_{ij}=\sum_r a_r\,Ex_ix_jX_rY_r,$$
where
$$X_r:=\sum_k s_{rk}x_k,\quad Y_r:=\sum_k t_{rl}x_l.$$
For each $(i,r)$, the CC of $Ex_iX_r$ and $Ex_iY_r$, as well as of $EX_rY_r$, is $O(d)$, which adds up to $O(d^3)$ for all $(i,r)$.
After that, because $x_i,x_j,X_r,Y_r$ are zero-mean jointly normal -- see e.g. the [Isserlis formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isserlis%27_theorem), for each $(i,j,r)$ the CC of $Ex_ix_jX_rY_r$ is $O(1)$ and hence the CC of $u_{ij}=\sum_r a_r\,Ex_ix_jX_rY_r$ is $O(d)$ for each $(i,j)$.

So, the overall CC is $O(d^3)$.

Comment: It seems this method destroys block structure. IE, if the matrix is block diagonal, one could do this in O(d) and cubic in block size. I suspect block tridiagonal is cheaper than general case

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov : You wrote: "if the matrix is block diagonal, one could do this in O(d) and cubic in block size." How can you do that? I see how to do this in $O(d^2b^2)$ steps, where $b$ is the largest block size, for a block-diagonal $J$. Also, in the definition of $p$ do you have $x'Jx$ or $x'J^{-1}x$? If $x'Jx$, then I don't see how the (block-)triagonality of $J$ can help at all.

Comment: You are right, even reading the vector takes $O(d^2)$ steps. I was confused after looking at a setting of v matrix being rank-1, where $O(d)$ is possible by applying Isserlis on a per-block basis